# find all devices in a network

Tags: android, c++, networking, udp

In my local network there are several devices (running linux, c++) and an Android Smartphone. 
Now I want to find and display all devices in the network on the Android Smartphone. Later i want to pair the android smart phone with the device for communication.
What's a good way to implement this?
My first ideas are:

- sending a udp broadcast from the android smartphone, and handle these requests on each device and return a udp packet with more informations about the device.

or

- When a device is active it periodically sends heartbeats as broadcast which the android smartphone can detect.

i also read about upnp, but i think this is kinda overkill.
Can you give me any hints how to implement this kind of task?

ty

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at nmap. It is a network scanner that can look through the network and find devices on it. Parse the output from it and display on the phone.